# Intern.js is failing to launch Chrome 37, or Latest FireFox 32

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intern

I am using the latest intern 2.0.3 against selenium-server-standalone 2.42.2, it works fine with FireFox 31 or Chrome 36. Firefox 32 hangs up and won't launch, as does Chrome > 36. I am sure it is in selenium-server and some change, not intern, but it is causing all auto-updating browsers to crash.

Comment: Most likely because that Selenium 2.42.2 only supports to Firefox 31 and Chrome 36. Please downgrade your browsers or wait for the next new Selenium release. For best practise, please disable auto-updating for browsers (It's auto-updating. i.e new versions causing Selenium to crash, not the other way around).

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour with the new firefox.

Comment: @YiZeng is right - this is a known issue with selenium 2.42.2 and Firefox 32: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @YiZeng pointed out, the problem is because Selenium 2.42.2 only supports up to Firefox 31 and Chrome 36. The solution is to downgrade your browsers or wait for the next new Selenium release.

Comment: This is true, and I just updated selenium-server and it works. There is a new npm package for selenium-server which is nicely updated.